# Return this in static function class

Tags: javascript, design-patterns, singleton

I have two objects, I want to make singleton class and then call them like this **Row.init([789]).render()**. In the first case I try and it works:

```
var Row = (function (options) {
        console.log(options);
        this.data = [123];
        this.render = function () {console.log(this.data);}
        this.init = function (data) {
            this.data = data;
            return this;
        }
        return this;
    })();
```

but in the second case:

```
class Row {
    constructor() {
        this.data = {};
    }
    static init(data) {
        this.data = data;
        return this;
    }
    fill() {
        return this;
    }
    render() {
        console.log(this.data);
    }
}
```

It cannot call render method, I think it doesnt return this for me. How do I fix it? And in the first case, how do I pass options parameter?

Comment: Just drop the `static`. It's not 'static' in your first example.

Comment: @yunzen I cannot see static keyword in first example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's no longer a singleton when you use a class. You need to create an instance in the `init` function:

```
class Row {
    constructor() {
        this.data = {};
    }
    static init(data) {
        return new this(data);
    }
    fill() {
        return this;
    }
    render() {
        console.log(this.data);
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks, it works. How about options parameter in first case? How do I pass it?

Comment: @MayWeatherVN The `options` parameter in your first snippet should be the argument to your IIFE, if that's what you mean. `…})('some options');`